# My border effect isn't working properly when hovering

Tags: html, list

I am designing a simple list with little CSS. In this design, if the user hovers over a list item it will highlight the top and bottom border. But, except for the last one hover, only one border is highlighted.

If I remove `margin-bottom: -1px;` then it is displaying `2px` border.

```css
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.list-item {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeef;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.list-item:hover {
  color: #0275d8;
  border-top: 1px solid #0275d8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0275d8;
  
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 1</li>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 2</li>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 3</li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KiranChauhan/es9bjdw9/2/)

Comment: But between the fist and second li you have a 2px border too. Do you want that ?

Comment: I can't recreate your issue when removing `margin-bottom: -1px;`. What browser are you using?

Comment: @theoretisch: no. I don't want 2px border to show. only 1px to display.

Comment: @Roberrrt: mozilla, chorme. You will see 2px (little thing than what you are seeing previously) except first and last border.

Comment: Not having this problem on Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `.list-item` below still has a `#eeeeef` border-top. An easy way to fix this is to say the next `.list-item` should have a the border-top changed to `#0275d8` too.

We can do that like this:

```css
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.list-item {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: solid #eeeeef;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.list-item:hover {
  color: #0275d8;
  border-color: #0275d8;
}

/* next .list-item */
.list-item:hover + .list-item {
  border-top-color: #0275d8;
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 1</li>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 2</li>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 3</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ahh ok good, I thought the line between the first and second li should be 1px too.

Comment: @Kiran I've done a little bit of optimisation to the CSS now too.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. Its not a beautiful solution but it works I think.

```css
.list {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0;
}
.list-item {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
.list-item:hover{
    color: #0275d8;
    border-color: #0275d8;
}
li:hover + li {
    border-top-color: #0275d8;
}
li:last-child{
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 1</li>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 2</li>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its work but still showing gray bottom border right below there when you hover.

Comment: @Kiran I fixed it try it

Comment: Yes, but @Andrew's one is more clean. Als your `li` style is effeting my other `li` !

Comment: Yes I thought you want that all lines are 1px.

Comment: @theoretisch use :last-child rather than having a bottom class 

Answer (score -1):

Please apply this class. change the `margin bottom:-1px` to `0px`

```css
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.list-item {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeef;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.list-item:hover {
  color: #0275d8;
  border-top: 1px solid #0275d8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0275d8;
  
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 1</li>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 2</li>
  <li class='list-item'>Sample List 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please check this

Comment: Have you checked that it is showing 2px border normally?

Comment: Do we need to add 2px for bottom and top for 1px ?